# How to pass JSON object to IBM Watson Assistant through an action?

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I have an instance of Watson Assistant that I want to use to provide calculation services for my site's users. I followed the doc [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions) and the service seems to correctly pick up the slots for each bit of information and my client app's method tests properly as well. I'm not sure why I can't access the response sent back by my method to the node.

Here's my client method:

```js
function fraisCar(action){
    if (action.puissance <= 3) {
      if(action.kilometres <= 5000){
        var bareme = action.kilometres * 0.41;
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 5000 && action.kilometres <= 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.245) + 824
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.286)
      }
    }
    
   if (action.puissance == 4) {
     if(action.kilometres <= 5000){
        var bareme = action.kilometres * 0.493;
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 5000 && action.kilometres <= 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.277) + 1082
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.332)
      }
   }
   if (action.puissance == 5) {
     if(action.kilometres <= 5000){
        var bareme = action.kilometres * 0.543;
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 5000 && action.kilometres <= 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.305) + 1188
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.364)
      }
   }
    if (action.puissance == 5) {
     if(action.kilometres <= 5000){
        var bareme = action.kilometres * 0.543;
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 5000 && action.kilometres <= 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.305) + 1188
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.364)
      }
   }
   if (action.puissance == 6) {
     if(action.kilometres <= 5000){
        var bareme = action.kilometres * 0.568;
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 5000 && action.kilometres <= 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.32) + 1244
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.382)
      }
   }
   if (action.puissance > 6) {
     if(action.kilometres <= 5000){
        var bareme = action.kilometres * 0.595;
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 5000 && action.kilometres <= 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.337) + 1288
      }
      if(action.kilometres > 20000){
        var bareme = (action.kilometres * 0.401)
      }
   }
   var frais = bareme + action.fraisGarage + action.fraisPeage + action.fraisEmprunt;
   return {frais: frais};
}
```

[and here's my JSON editor in Watson.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBznK.png)

I have tried jumping to a child node immediately after the action is carried out in order to prevent user input from being expected before showing the message, using output.frais and  as well and nothing works.

What's the best way to access the value of the return object and automatically embed it in a Watson response?

And if I have simpler calculations to do like multiplication, how do I go about using the java.lang.Math class within the dialog nodes to do it? I tried the syntax in the docs and it's just not complete for some reason.

**Note:** I don't want to perform a server action with IBM Cloud Functions, just a client call.

Comment: I would recommend asking the math functions in a separate question. For how to react on the return of an action, I covered that in this tutorial: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html

Comment: Is that still open? I have working examples.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the action will be stored in a `context` variable `frais`. It can be then access anywhere from dialog by writing `$frais` or `<? context.frais ?>`.

To display that variable in an output simply write in your dialog node response field: `"This is the value of context.frais: $frais ."`.

Comment: hi there, i have done this, it does not work :( it seems the object being returned is inaccessible to the child nodes even when using skip_user_input: true

Comment: Then I would try to debug the cloud function code itself - did the call ended up successfully? Was there something returned? 
The moment it is stored in the dialog `context` field then it can be accessed in any dialog node.

Now I realized that you are not using cloud functions to resolve the action - so the action is resolved by the client. The client then needs t o inject the resulting object into `context.frais` and send it back to the server.